# How to get drop down text in mat-select using angular 6

Tags: html, angular6, dropdown

Here is is my code HTML:

```html
<mat-list-item class="primary-imenu-item" role="listitem">
    <mat-select class="form-control" multiple formControlName="statusCode" (selectionChange)="getSelectedOptionText($event)">
        <mat-option *ngFor="let list of statusList" [value]="list.id" checkboxPosition="before">
            {{list.code}}
        </mat-option>
    </mat-select>
</mat-list-item>
```

TS Code:

```js
getSelectedOptionText(event: MatSelectChange) {
    let selectedData = {
        code: (event.source.selected as MatOption).viewValue,
        value: event.source.value
    };

    console.log(selectedData);
}
```

In that 'selectedData' I am getting  the code value is undefined. I need to get code value from dropdown.

Comment: What does this have to with C# and ASP.NET?

Comment: @MindSwipe i need to pass those text  values from angular service to asp.net core solution.

Comment: But it seems like you problem, or at least the one described in your question, only has something to do with your frontend Angular application, and nothing to do with your backend

Answer (score 1):

The event object has "value" array attribute which will always have one item. So, instead of `(event.source.selected as MatOption).viewValue`, you can do `event.value[0]`. Look at the screenshot for more details. Hope it helps.

[image]

Comment: HI, In above screen shot its showing value of the selected item. but it should get text of the selected item. thank for your reply. @rohit

Comment: text is already working for you I think which is being correctly being populated in "value" attribute of selectedData.

Comment: Can you mark this as answer and upvote it if it helped you?